# Install SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows XP sp3 causes an error (.netframework 2)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows XP sp3.

Before I install SQL Server, I installed the .net Framework 4. But I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 Express, but I get this error :

> SQL Server 2008 requires Microsoft .net Framework 2 sp2 to be installed

Why is this error shown when I installed .net 4 ?

Comment: Because .Net 2 SP2 is required ... i.e. it is the only .Net Framework supported for CLR UDFs.

Comment: It is time to move of XP BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because .NET 2.0-3.x and .NET 4.x are using two separate runtime and should be installed separately. The two runtimes (CLR 2.0 & CLR 4.0) can be installed side-by-side.